# Какой знак препинания нужно поставить перед "разглядеть"?

Tags: пунктуация

Они ли это были или не они разглядеть не представлялось возможным"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом бессоюзном сложном предложении я бы поставила тире. Думаю, что вторая часть имеет присоединительное значение (перед ней можно поставить слово "это").

**Они ли это были или не они —** [это] **разглядеть не представлялось возможным.**

[Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/755-32_znacheniya_slozhnyh_bessoyuznyh_predlozhenii_i_znaki_prepinaniya_v_nih.html)